# What could be the reason of auto datetime conversion in java api response

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, datetime, rest

I created one simple model class `User`. I used Util date here.

```java
class User{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Date createdAt;
}
```

On user post API call, I simply do `setCreatedAt(new Date)`.

The problem is in the response, I am getting createdAt as -5.30 of the actual time. No additional time conversion method is called.

For Example, I hit the POST API user created at `28-10-2021 11:30:00` which I can see in the logs. But when it returns the response to the postman it shows `28-10-2021 06:00:00` time. There is no time conversion method in the code. I checked the return object in the return statement in debug mode even there is showing `28-10-2021 11:30:00`.

- I wanted to know where is this conversion happening. And how to stop this.
- If it's the problem with datetime library, then which one should I use.

```
Extra information:
 * My system timezone is in UTC. 
 * I am using ubuntu.
 * Creating restFull APIs(JaxRs)
```

EDIT 1:
client and server are on the same machine(UTC timezone). For client, I am using Postman.
URL: [POST] /user
Request Body:

```json
{
  "name": "XYZ"
}
```

Actual Response:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ",
  "createdAt: "28-10-2021 06:00:00"
}
```

Expected Response:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ",
  "createdAt: "28-10-2021 11:30:00"
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a simple cause: client and server are using different time zones which influence the conversion between the date object and the text representation the API uses. Can you add details on the API?

Comment: The server and client are on the same machine(UTC). For more detail, I edit the post. Please let me know what else is required.

Comment: It seems the API interprets the time as UTC but Postman might be using IST. "Client and server are on the same machine(UTC time zone)." - they could still be configured differently.

Comment: Your update seems to support that: the date seems to be created in UTC but your system clock would be in ITC (or whatever you use to determine the expected time). So 11:30 IST is 06:00 UTC (the same instant) and thus converting the date to a UTC string returns 06:00.

Comment: [Still using java.util.Date? Don’t!](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)

Comment: @GeroldBroser true :) However, don't use `LocalDateTime` as you might be tempted to do, but use `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, that, or depending on requirements, `Instant`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` or another appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

> On user post API call, I simply do setCreatedAt(new Date).

It appears that you have not set the timezone while creating an instance of java.util.Date

By default it will set as UTC irrespective of your system timezone. You can use the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html instead.

```
final TIMEZONE = ""; // need to set the timezone here
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIMEZONE));

String dateInString = "28-10-2021 11:30:00"; 
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be JsonFormat annotations that have timeZone issues. Please check the link for more details on the issue.[jackson-data-bind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1266) issue Overriding the timezone in ObjectMapper didn't work either. You can refer the solved example by implementing a custom Date Deserializer as below:

```
@Component
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); // specify your specific timezone

     public CustomDateDeserializer() {
         this(null);
     }  

     public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
         super(vc);
     }

     @Override
     public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
                         throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
         String date = jsonparser.getText();
         try {
             return formatter.parse(date);
         } catch (ParseException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
     }
}
```

Also, add the deserializer on the setter method in your bean properties.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
public void setReturnDateTime(Date returnDateTime) {
this.returnDateTime = returnDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This change on properties file made the trick for me :

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE = false
```